# Better choice of Queue then a ConcurrentLinkedQueue if I have low number of threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have two threads, one that is reading messages from the web and putting them into some sort of a queue. The other is suppose to read it. I looked into a ConcurrentLinkedQueue and it looks good for my purpose. But when I was scanning through the documentation I see this:

" A ConcurrentLinkedQueue is an appropriate choice when many threads will share access to a common collection."

This quote got me wondering if this tool would be an overkill for my scenario. What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Use it, profile it, see if there is a problem, [check out the implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java), reevaluate decision.

Comment: I believe this text is using the same definition of "many" as is used in, for example, the phrase "many-to-one relationship", I.e. "potentially more than one".

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Also I would like this to work on multiple platforms, including android